# I'm developing a database with entry data forms in libreoffice Base, how can I hide the background app and show the forms and subforms only?

Tags: libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-base

I don't want users can see the tables, bar menu, etc of main Base app, I need users only can see the forms and subforms to enter data or show reports from search queries at the database.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Look at these [**four lines**](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=34214&p=156973#p156975)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the visibility of any window is simple:

```
Sub setVisibleMainWindow(bVisible As Boolean)
    ThisDataBaseDocument.getCurrentController().getFrame().getContainerWindow().setVisible(bVisible)
End Sub
```

Only call this procedure when opening the form. For example, like this:

```
Sub openDefaultForm( )
Const MAIN_FORM_NAME = "DataForm"
    If ThisDatabaseDocument.FormDocuments.hasbyname(MAIN_FORM_NAME) Then 
        ThisDataBaseDocument.CurrentController.Connect() 
        ThisDatabaseDocument.CurrentController.loadComponent(com.sun.star.sdb.application.DatabaseObject.FORM, MAIN_FORM_NAME, FALSE) 
        setVisibleMainWindow(False)
    Else
        MsgBox "Something happened to the " & MAIN_FORM_NAME & " form!"+ chr(10)+"You deleted? Or renamed?" , 48, "Form not found"
    End if
End Sub
```

And don't forget to make this window visible before shutting down:

```
Sub beforeClose(oEvent As Variant)
    setVisibleMainWindow(True)
End Sub
```

Now use [**Tools - Customize - Events tab**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.3/en-US/text/shared/01/06140500.html) to assign the `openDefaultForm()` procedure as the database's "Open Document" event handler, and the `beforeClose()` procedure as the "Document is going to be closed" event handler for the form.